# What is the difference between `./example.sh` and `sh example.sh`

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to play with bash and arrays. But executing a sample script, I got an unexpected syntax error message: `example.sh: 3: example.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. And this is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( one two three )
```

If I run the script with ./example.sh it works and no errors are displayed. But if I run `sh example.sh` I get the error message.

I thought that these two commands are the same:

- sh example.sh
- ./example.sh

so ... what is the difference between the two?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/97614/what-exactly-is-the-sh-command

Comment: sh example.sh calls the /bin/sh executable which may or may not be the same as /bin/bash on your system. Compare the output of sh --version and bash --version for more details.

Comment: In either case, I'm not sure it ought to make a difference. Does quoting your string values make a difference?

Comment: I am just a "junior" bash developer. I did not thought that `sh` or `bash` has different meaning o_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_name=(value1 ... valuen)
```

This is how to initializes an array in `bash` only. When you execute `./example.sh`, the shebang line  `#!/bin/bash` tells the system to use `bash` to execute.

However, when you execute `sh example.sh`, `sh` is used to execute. In many Unix systems (like Linux), `sh` is equivalent to `bash`. It seems `sh` is a different shell on your system.

Comment: sh is different from bash (I didnt though). thank you very much. Mmm can you suggest me a good source to study all this stuffs? I think I cant find good information source alone: I dont know the answer. Any book?

Answer (score 3):

When you launch it via `./example.sh` then the command specified in the first line of the script is used to interpret the content. So your script executes in a `bash`, where such syntax is allowed for arrays.

When you launch it via `sh example.sh` then `sh` is the command that is used to interpret the content of the file. `sh` is the original Unix shell (aka Bourne shell) and this shell is a little more rude than `bash` (Bourne again shell). You don't have such arrays. Note that in `sh` the first line of your script is just interpreted as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

by using sh example.sh
 - you are specifying what shell interpreter to use for that script. Example being "bash example.sh" instead of "sh example.sh" etc etc.

Running scripts this way disregards the "shebang (#!/bin/bash)" that you have specified inside of the script. Since you wrote a bash script but are trying to run it as just "sh", this is why it is failing

by using ./example.sh, 
 - You are specifying to run the script from your current directory. This will attempt to run the script in whatever shell you are currently in unless a shebang is specified. Since you have a "shebang" specified to run the script in bash... this is why it is working.