# Difference between ./script-name.sh and sh script-name.sh while running a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What's the difference b/w running a script using ./script-name and running it  using sh scriptname.sh ? I have this script which runs ok when I run it using ./script.sh but doesn't when I run it using sh script.sh . What changes I have to make it work?

Comment: Didn't this get asked before?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907988/what-is-the-difference-between-example-sh-and-sh-example-sh

Answer (score 0):

`./script_name` require the script to have `x` permission for the user, and its first line `shabang` indicate its interpreter. e.g `#! /bin/bash`

`interpreter_name script_name` don't require the `x` permission.