# Different outputs using ./ and sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Consider this example snippet:

```
copy=true
model="model"
if [ ${copy} = true ] ; then
    model+="Copy"
fi
echo ${model}
```

I am on the following platform:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Output using `sh test.sh`:

```
test2.sh: 4: test2.sh: model+=Copy: not found ---> error
model
```

Output using `./test.sh`:

```
modelCopy
```

I am aware of some of the differences between running the bash script using `sh` and `./` after reading links[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996612/echo-output-different-answer-by-sh-and-bash), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907988/what-is-the-difference-between-example-sh-and-sh-example-sh)]. Still, I would like to know what's wrong with the use of `+=` operator when I use `sh`, why it doesn't work. I am some use-cases where I need to run the file using `sh` only, how can I rectify that `not found` error?

Comment: Because `sh` is not `bash`, so that means your script has a `bash` shebang but you invoke it with `sh`. the `+=` is not supported in `sh`.

Comment: Your shell is probably `bash`. Without a shebang, `bash` will use itself to execute `./test.sh`. `sh`, meanwhile, is probably a link to a shell other than `bash`: the error message shown is consistent with what `dash` would do with `model+=Copy`.

Comment: So, what could be the equivalent command if I want to use `sh`?

Comment: The `sh` way to append to a variable is `model="${model}Copy"`. Please note that running `sh somescript` is bad practice and if something makes you do that, then you should fix that situation (it's not necessarily a bad idea to make this a `sh` script instead of a `bash` script, but you should still avoid `sh somescript`)

Comment: @thatotherguy What's wrong with `sh somescript` if the script is POSIX-compliant? You're going to get the same result as if you make the script executable and use an equivalent shebang.

Comment: It's bad practice because it hardcodes the shell type and options in each invocation, instead of centralizing that information in the script itself.